# wrongly selected id from db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very strange problem with my php app.
I have a page where I print all "Open RFQs" like this:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
   <h2 class="mb-3">Open RFQs</h2>
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>RFQ Number</th>
               <th>Title</th>
               <th>Variant</th>
               <th>Due Date</th>
               <th>Priority</th>
               <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <?php
               try {
                   $sql = "SELECT * FROM rfq WHERE status = 'Sent'"; // ako ima oshte filtri da gi sloja tuk
                   $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
                   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                       echo "<tr>";
                       echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['rfq_number']) . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['title']) . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['variant']) . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['due_date']) . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['priority']) . "</td>";
                       echo "<td><a href='submit_offer.php?rfq_id=" . $row['id'] . "' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit Offer</a></td>";
                       echo "</tr>";
                   }
               } catch (PDOException $e) {
                   echo "<tr><td colspan='7'>Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "</td></tr>";
               }
               ?>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

This works fine but the problem comes when I click on Submit Offer.
As you can see is leading to submit_offer.php for example `submit_offer.php?rfq_id=14`
inside rfq_id = 14 I have two items that can be quoted with `item_id 18` and `item_id 19`.
Fine, in submit_offer.php I have this:

```
$rfqId = $_GET['rfq_id'];
$sql11 = "SELECT * FROM rfq WHERE id = :rfq_id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql11);
$stmt->execute(['rfq_id' => $rfqId]);
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result) {
        $rfqnr = $result['rfq_number'];
    } else {
        echo "No result found.";
    }
```

and also I have a form where user is able to quote items related to this rfq number (14)

```
<form action="process_offer_submission.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="rfq_id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($rfqId); ?>">

    <?php
    try {
        // da zeme header informaciqta
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM rfq WHERE id = :rfq_id";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(['rfq_id' => $rfqId]);
        while ($main = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<div class='mb-3'>"; // Start of form group
        echo "<label for='title' class='form-label'>RFQ Title</label>";
        echo "<input type='text' id='title' class='form-control' name='title' value='" . htmlspecialchars($main['title']) . "' readonly>";
        
        echo "<label for='rfqDescription' class='form-label mt-2'>RFQ Description</label>";
        echo "<textarea id='rfqDescription' class='form-control' name='rfqdescription[]' readonly>" . htmlspecialchars($main['general_description']) . "</textarea>";
        
        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div class='col-md-6 mt-2'>";
        echo "<label for='dueDate' class='form-label'>Due Date</label>";
        echo "<input type='date' id='dueDate' class='form-control' name='due_date[]' value='" . htmlspecialchars($main['due_date']) . "' readonly>";
        echo "</div>";
        
        echo "<div class='col-md-6 mt-2'>";
        echo "<label for='priority' class='form-label'>Priority</label>";
    
        // Check if priority is "Urgent"
        if ($main['priority'] == "Urgent") {
            echo "<input type='text' id='priority' class='form-control text-danger' name='priority[]' value='" . htmlspecialchars($main['priority']) . "' readonly>";
        } else {
            echo "<input type='text' id='priority' class='form-control' name='priority[]' value='" . htmlspecialchars($main['priority']) . "' readonly>";
        }
    
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>"; // End of row
        echo "</div>"; // End of form group
    }
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "<div style='text-align:center'> <p> Items Information </p> </div> <br>";
        echo "<table class='table'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Item Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Description</th>";
        echo "<th>Quantity</th>";
        echo "<th>File</th>";
        echo "<th>Your Price</th>";
        echo "<th>Your Delivery Time</th>";
        echo "<th>Your Remarks</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        
        $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM rfq_items
            LEFT JOIN rfq_item_attachments ON rfq_items.id = rfq_item_attachments.rfq_item_id
            WHERE rfq_items.rfq_id = :rfq_id;
            ";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(['rfq_id' => $rfqId]);
        
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Fetched Item ID: " . $row['id'] . "<br>";  // Debugging line
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['item_name']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['description']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['quantity']) . "</td>";

    // Check if file_path is not empty and create a downloadable link
    if (!empty($row['file_path'])) {
        echo "<td><a href='" . htmlspecialchars($row['file_path']) . "' download>Download</a></td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td>No file</td>";
    }

    echo "<td><input type='number' name='price[]' placeholder='Price' class='form-control'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='date' name='delivery_time[]' placeholder='Pick Date' class='form-control'></td>";
    echo "<td><textarea name='description[]' placeholder='Description' class='form-control'></textarea></td>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_id[]' value='" . htmlspecialchars($row['id']) . "'>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

        
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit Offer</button>
</form>
```

Looks good right ? NOT!
as you can see I have placed:

```
echo "Fetched Item ID: " . $row['id'] . "<br>";  // Debugging line
```

here comes the strange part output of the debug line is:

```
Fetched Item ID: 17
Fetched Item ID: 18
```

Those are not correct!
but in the form, I am seeing the correct ones (18 and 19) printed.
Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Please provide sample data from the database, and expected result. It seems like basically a SQL question

Comment: `but in the form`...which form, and where exactly do you see this? I don't think it's obvious from the code. Your post could be clearer, quite honestly. We can't see your screen or your database, remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` can return multiple rows for the same `rfq_items`, for each attatchment it will return a new row. So if you have multiple attachments for the same `rfq_items` you will get multiple rows with the same `rfq_items` `id`. A second problem is that the `id` column might be ambiguous, both the `rfq_items` and `attachments` could have a column named `id`, you can prevent this problem by using an alias for the id column.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have changed my query like this:
`SELECT rfq_items.id AS item_id, rfq_items.*, rfq_item_attachments.*
                        FROM rfq_items
                        LEFT JOIN rfq_item_attachments ON rfq_items.id = rfq_item_attachments.rfq_item_id
                        WHERE rfq_items.rfq_id = :rfq_id;`

Now is working good.